# What is the best way to test how many times is a component being rendered during a map using React Testing Library + Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component `InvoiceItem` which should be rendered as many times as the number of invoices in an array. Let's say I have an array called `filteredData` which I then map it as such:

**Invoices.js**

```js
function Invoices() {
    return (
       {filteredData.map(inv => {
           <InvoiceItem
                data={inv}
           />
       })}
    )
}
```

and inside the `InvoiceItem` component, there is a wrapping `div` which I give a test-id as such:

```js
function InvoiceItem() {
    return (
        <div data-testid="invoice-list-item">
            ...
        </div>
    )
}
```

How can I test that the number of times `InvoiceItem` being rendered is correct? Note that `filteredData` is a state which changes according to a search result. Hence I want to check if the number of render is correct when a search is being done. What I've done so far:

```js
import React from "react";
import { render, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import Invoices from "..";
import { data, userId } from "./testConstants.js"

describe(Invoices, () => {
  it("Number of invoice list item is rendered correctly according to search input", async () => {
    const component = render(<Invoices data={data} />);
    fireEvent.change(component.getByTestId("search-input"), {
      target: { value: "wow" },
    });
    const items = component.getAllByTestId("invoice-list-item");
    expect(items.length).toBe(2); // There should be 2 items with the name "wow"
  });
});
```

However, this ends up with Jest not being able to detect test-id with `invoice-list-item`. What am I doing wrong here? Or is there a better approach to this problem?

## Additional Information

I'm not doing any API call in this component, in the web I'm just pulling data from redux and I've done it through this complete `Invoices.test.js`:

```js
import React from "react";
import { render as rtlRender, fireEvent } from "@testing-library/react";
import Invoices from "..";
import { data, userId } from "./testConstants";

import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "redux/store";

const render = (component) =>
  rtlRender(<Provider store={store}>{component}</Provider>);

describe(Invoices, () => {
  it("Number of invoice list item is rendered correctly according to search input", async () => {
    const component = render(<Invoices userId={userId} data={data} />);
    fireEvent.change(component.getByTestId("search-input"), {
      target: { value: "bacardi" },
    });
    const items = component.getAllByTestId("invoice-list-item");
    expect(items.length).toBe(3);
  });
});
```